# PartialLoop with Zend_Paginator Object Issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

Is it possible to use the `findParentRow()` method from within a Zend_Paginator Object? I'm trying some code that works fine on an object returned by fetchAll from a DB resultset and works fine. With the Zend_Paginator object it doesnt work though.

In my controller i have:

```
public function downloadedAction()
{
    $images = new Model_ApplicationImages();
    $paginator = $images->fetchPaginated();
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
}
```

In my model i have:

```
public function fetchPaginated()
{
    $select = $this->select()
                   ->from($this->_name)
                   ->where('status = ?','approved')
                   ->where('downloaded = ?','0');
    $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    return $paginator;
}
```

In my view i have:

```
    $this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('paginator');
    echo $this->partialLoop('admin/list-downloaded.phtml', $this->paginator);
```

and in the partial:

```
    $this->paginator->findParentRow('Model_Application')->name
```

It appears though that the object key is not being used or not being set properly as within the partial `var_dump($this->paginator)` is `NULL` and the other values being passed from the paginator are there but under `$this->key` and not `$this->paginator->key` as they should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `PartialLoop` essentially runs a `Partial` for each element in the array or `Traversable` object passed to it. So by the time it gets to your partial view script, you're no longer working with the `Paginator` object, but with its paginated contents.

In a partial loop, the `setObjectKey()` works at the partial level. You can pass an array of `Traversable` objects (or a `Traversable` object that iterates over `Traversable` objects) to a partial loop and in the partial each object will then be accessible through the object key.

The `DbSelect` paginator adapter you're using, however, returns an *array* of rows for each page, so there isn't any object to be put in the `paginator` object key and it remains unused.

You should use the `DbTableSelect` adapter instead, which will return a rowset.

If you need access to the Paginator itself you should use a partial instead. That way you can use `setObjectKey()` to loop over the pages in the paginator yourself.

I suggest you keep the source code of the Zend Framework handy when something doesn't work the way you expect. Sadly, I've had more success figuring out how to use it by reading through the code than by reading through the documentation.

Comment: I don't know has it was before, but a partialLoop *can* have a setObjectKey() method. And the model has to implement `Iterator`, not Traversable.

Comment: @nevvermind, `PartialLoop` extends `Partial`, so yes it does have `setObjectKey()`. But when you pass an object to `partialLoop()` it will first iterate over that, and only *then* use `setObjectKey()` to set the item in each partial in the loop. Since he was using the `DbSelect` paginator adapter, the resulting item was an *array* of database rows for that page, not an object, so `setObjectKey()` didn't work.

Comment: @nevvermind, and the model has to be `Traversable`, [that's what ZF checks for](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/View/Helper/PartialLoop.php), but [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) itself has no interface and needs to be implemented using either `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate`.

Comment: @nevvermind, thanks for making me have another look at my answer! I've fixed it up a bit.

Comment: ZF Docs: `It allows you to pass an iterable item (array or object implementing Iterator) as the model`. I didn't know you can't actually implement `Traversable`. Now I know what you mean by `Sadly, I've had more success figuring out how to use it by reading through the code than by reading through the documentation`. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the sample code you provided is quite correct, I have very similar setup, albeit I used Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect as an adapter. So, it is definitely possible in principle.

It is worth checking what is returned from fetchPaginated(), in your controller action.

The other thing probably worth checking, is whether $view->paginator doesn't get overwritten in your view script (which is a bad thing for separate reasons). Plus, you can actually play with object key name, use "model" for example instead of "paginator" in your setObjectKey().

P.S. Not sure whether it is relevant or not, but I setup the object key in controller:

```
$this->view->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('model');
$this->view->partial()->setObjectKey('model');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getItems()` method of `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect` returns array and `getItems()` method of `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect` rowset, just use `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect`, not `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect`...